# Unusual reputation evolution for certain users: 1 without a ban, downvotes, or bounty

Tags: bug, reputation

Found some strange stuff at Security SE - there are users with a bunch of upvoted Q's and A's but reputation mysteriously at 1. No sign of a ban, bounty, or downvotes.

- https://security.stackexchange.com/users/43630/luke-rehmann
- https://security.stackexchange.com/users/42059/mboelen

EDIT: a SEDE query to find possibly penalized users is here: https://data.stackexchange.com/security/query/edit/302738

Comment: Any reason this wasn't posted on the Security meta?

Comment: @Oded - A feeling that this may be not site-specific. Please feel free to migrate at will, though :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took a look at both profiles.

Both had posts that were flagged as spam and deleted as such - this caused a 100 rep penalty, resulting in their current reputation.

Comment: We can't see a -100 on their reputation history, so not so *obvious* to us by looking at their profile.