# How many user accounts on SE sites get hacked per year?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, spam, statistics, security

I've run a few queries for users with spam penalties across SE sites ([SEDE link](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/302738/spam-penalty)) and it occurred to me that there may be some accounts that were hacked into and used for posting spam. While this is **highly** unlikely (considering the ease of posting as an unregistered or first-time user), would like to know the statistics: how many SE users find their accounts hacked and used for spam posting?

Comment: All the accounts that suddenly see the error of their ways when they've been suspended for it

Comment: A couple of notes that might make this difficult-to-impossible to answer. (1) Accounts used to post spam are typically destroyed; (2) users flag all sorts of things as "spam" including stuff they simply don't like or don't agree with, so there's no way to query how many "spam penalties" actually mean what you think.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - in other words, has any user account at SE been hacked? If yes, then how many? It is hard to believe no users have fallen prey to password leaks at other sites/social engineering/phishing etc.

Comment: @DeerHunter I don't really know. Users' claims of "it wasn't me" are not verified. Stuff flagged as spam does not always mean spam. The activity either stops or the account is destroyed. No records are kept correlating hacking attempts with posting spam, so I don't know how you would even *begin* to query this without incurring an error of +/- 99.9% give or take. Sorry.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - looks like *the* answer, as authoritative as it can get.

Comment: Related: [This is not my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253811/this-is-not-my-profile)

Comment: lol, I was just going to mention this...

Answer (score -1):

> would like to know the statistics: how many SE users find their
>   accounts hacked and used for spam posting

Well, firstly it goes without saying that Stack wouldn't give up such information, even if they had it.
They might give you certain data, but I doubt anything which is not already present publicly *now* - data around the site and through SEDE.

While it's entirely possible an account used for posting spam has been hacked, this is not *always* true.
And even if Stack gave you a load of spam related data, it alone won't give you any decent data to draw to any accurate conclusions. Not without all sorts of other account related data - login times/dates, IP addresses, etc - none of which will never be made public.

Unfortunately, I would guess you'll have to do your own work for this. Getting a list of accounts used for spamming, then assessing when the account was last used, what activity was performed on the account prior to the spam, what type of spam was it, etc.

Then you can get some patterns and build up a picture to show if the account seemed to suddenly change course.

Again, none of this will be accurate, and there will be a lot of assumptions and guesswork.

And, while none of my business, I'm not sure why you want this info.
Given the fact Stack sites are secure, any hacking will be through methods out of Stack's control - someone follows a link to a dodgy site, or their Gmail has been hacked away from Stack, etc.

Are you just curious? Or..?

Comment: Curious I am. There's a distinction between penalized users and deleted accounts, and while I'm not concerned with deleted accounts, it's interesting to have a look at stats for bona fide (sans the penalty) SE dwellers.

Comment: This question also grew out of this one: [Unusual reputation evolution for certain users: 1 without a ban, downvotes, or bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253735/)