# This is not my profile

Tags: support, profile-page

I have signed into(automatically) a profile that is not mine. I was browsing StackOverflow with the user [Aniket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680957/Aniket).

I logged into [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and the name changed to Unknown with some Hungarian text.

The About Me and a lot of other data has changed. The About Me is now

> A leginkább technológiailag hatékony gép, amelyet az ember valaha is kitalált a könyv
>
> Csak azért, mert valami nem csinál, amit terveztem csinálni nem jelenti azt, hogy haszontalan

I don't know Hungarian even and even the email address everything has changed to Unknown, my picture is gone what the hell is going on?

My reputation, questions and answers are all intact.

The email address has changed to: `reach_devil@outlook.com` and name as "you will know soon".

Comment: It looks like someone is either playing a joke on you or you're being cyber-harrassed/attacked. I'm not sure there's much we can do. Have you signed in anywhere public recently?

Comment: Nope, not recently anywhere.

Comment: @Unknown It's Saturday, so I'm not sure who's around, but we'll look into this ASAP.

Comment: It's funny how someone asked for the number of hacked SE accounts the other day.

Comment: @MARamezani - yup, although it's not fun to be pwned.

Comment: @DeerHunter Indeed - But let's not forget that The lack of caution is the cause.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After reviewing your account history, it appears that someone gained access to a logged-in session with your account, from an IP address you'd previously accessed your account from back in November. The most likely possibility here is that you left your account logged in on a machine that someone else had (or gained) access to.

They then proceeded to change your email, edited your name and about me section, and added new credentials (by creating their own account and merging it in).

I responded to your email with more details that might help you figure out how this happened.

Comment: thank you.. thanks a lot I received your email and responded back to the same email address

Comment: thank you folks.. you're the best! awesome support and help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

I think you need to contact the team on this one.

Looking at your profile I can see some things that I'd rather not go into publicly, but could have a bearing on what's happened here.

Did you contact the team at some point before 14th April about your account?

Comment: not yet, I am about to email this one to them

Comment: lets hope this issue is resolved at the earliest.

Comment: I didnot contact the team before 14th at all!